# Adding a drop-down submenu to a navigation menu increases the height to the container

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating my own wordpress theme and
I took help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092684/how-to-add-a-dropdown-to-this-simple-navbar) link to create a drop-down submenu.

The problem is while hovering over the navigation menu, I want the submenu to appear like this-
[image]

and it looks like this originally -

[image]
and after hovering it looks like this -
[image]

How to rectify this so that the height of the top level menu stays as it is and the submenu appears like the one in the first image?

The code is given below-
CSS:

```
.site-nav ul ul 
{
    display: none;
}

.site-nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Wordpress HTML + PHP code

```
       <nav class="site-nav">
            <?php 
                $args=array(
                    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                    'menu'            => '',
                    'container'       => 'div',
                    'container_class' => '',
                    'container_id'    => '',
                    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
                    'menu_id'         => '',
                    'echo'            => true,
                    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                    'before'          => '',
                    'after'           => '',
                    'link_before'     => '',
                    'link_after'      => '',
                    'items_wrap'      => my_nav_wrap(),
                    'depth'           => 2,
                    'walker'          => ''
                );
            ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
        </nav>
```

This is the rendered HTML code :

```
<nav class="site-nav">
    <div class="menu-cf-menu-test-container">
        <ul id="menu-cf-menu-test" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1561" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1553 current_page_item menu-item-1561">
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1553">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1243">
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1220">About</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1535" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1535">
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1214">Program Implementation</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1283" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1283">
                <a href="#">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1536" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1536">
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1371">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                <a href="/profile">Hi sid!</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/profile">View Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>                
</nav>
```

Comment: I put together a fiddle to try and see what's happening, but it isn't quite right. If you like, modify it and post your version. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ohbkq0px/

Comment: @isherwood, you've put exactly what is currently happening and I want to change it to the one in the first picture. I want to make my dropdown menu similar to Bootstrap's navbar menu but I'm unable to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72702/discussion-between-sidsec9-and-isherwood).

Answer (score -2):

This is close to the code that I use in my tabs:

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/item1/">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/item2/">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/item3/">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/item4/">Item 4</a></li>
```

Comment: @Dave please explain to the OP (and future SO visitors) why you did what you did. An explanation goes a long way towards making an answer good vs. average.

Comment: I gave an example of code that I use in my drop down menu. Code,that was already listed in the link that was supplied.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
    <div class="menu-cf-menu-test-container">
        <ul ><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1553">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1220">About</a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1214">Program Implementation</a>
            </li>
            <li i>
                <a href="#">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1371">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/profile">Hi sid!</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/profile">View Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>                
</nav>
```

This is how it should look

Comment: Dave, my question is partially related to your answer. What you answered shows how to create lists within lists and what I'm trying to figure out is how to create a drop-down submenu which doesn't increase the height of the container during a click or hover event.

Comment: It could be your CSS file. To make it simple. Follow the code posted. It will not increase the height. Keep it clean and simple. Use the <ul> to create the drop down, and the <li> for the sub menu. Make sure you have each line closed correctly. Doing divs and drop down menus is easy as writing hello world